# Long list of parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with a list of customers passed in as a parameter. This list has become quite large and found it hit the limit imposed by MaxHttpCollectionKeys. I've found this documented in several posts, but I now have a more specific issue.

I have set this a lot higher in the SSRS web.config file which has solved the problem when I access the report via the report manager (ServerName/Reports).  However this doesn't solve the problem when I render via the report server (ServerName/ReportServer).

I do need to access these reports via the report server as we pass some hidden parameters through from our App, as well as having some user selectable parameters. Searching for the solution only gives me posts related to the original solution which I've found.

Does anyone else have any ideas on solutions for this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found solution.

I didn't realise there are two web.config files.  One for the manager, one for the server.  These both needed to have the mod made. Needed to add the following code to the web.config file in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

Between the < system.web > and < runtime > tags.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />
</appSettings>
```